# Pandas el (read_csv usecols) no lee bien los datos

Tags: python, pandas, csv, openpyxl

Al leer un csv usando "read_csv usecols" y skipeando las columnas del archivo me genera un ".1" en una celda.

Necesitaría que ese carácter no aparezca al leer el csv, quiero que me traiga el archivo csv sin encabezado como lo esta trayendo pero sin ese carácter.

Archivo input:

```
#Librerias
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os

#Lee el archivo csv y lo filtra columnas en especifico con usecols
df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv", sep=";", usecols=[0,3,4,5,6,7], skiprows=1, header=0)
  
#Exporta el archivo csv
df.to_csv("archivo.csv", index=False)
```

#Archivo de salida con el carácter que aparece "OK.1" que debería aparece solo "OK" sin el .1

Archivo output:

```
 Tincho       Vivo       True         OK OK.1  --
0   Flaco  Fallecido       True         OK   OK  --
1  Pelado       Vivo  No existe  No existe   OK  --
2  Pajaro       Vivo  No existe  No existe   OK  --
```

Creo que el "OK.1" se debe a que no lo toma como fila inicial y me lo toma como si fueran encabezados, los encabezados los quito con skiprows=1, header=0:

Este es el archivo crudo que se importa quitando los encabezados:

```
    Nick     status    Fotolog        MSN Resultado Comentarios
0   Flaco  Fallecido       True         OK        OK          --
1  Pelado       Vivo  No existe  No existe        OK          --
2  Pajaro       Vivo  No existe  No existe        OK          --
```

Comment: Pon un sample del dataset

Comment: Disculpa no entendí, ¿te referís a archivo.csv que importo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pandas necesita un nombre para las columnas del DataFrame**, lo que ves con el `OK.1` no es una fila del DataFrame, son los nombres de las columnas del mismo... En concreto, `OK.1` es el nombre de la quinta columna.

`skiprows=1` hace que se descarte una linea del archivo y `header=0` le indica que use la primera linea del mismo como header (que se usara para nombrar las columnas del DataFrame). La primera linea (indice 0) tras descartar una linea es la segunda linea del csv y esa es la que se toma como *header* para nombrar las columnas del *DataFrame*.

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO(
"""\
Nick;;;status;Fotolog;MSN;Resultado;Comentarios
Flaco;;;Fallecido;True;OK;OK;--
Pelado;;;Vivo;No existe;No existe;OK;--
Pajaro;;;Vivo;No existe;No existe;OK;--
""")

df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", usecols=[0,3,4,5,6,7], skiprows=1, header=0)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>     Flaco Fallecido       True         OK OK.1  --
> 0  Pelado      Vivo  No existe  No existe   OK  --
> 1  Pajaro      Vivo  No existe  No existe   OK  --
>
> >>> df.columns
> Index(['Flaco', 'Fallecido', 'True', 'OK', 'OK.1', '--'], dtype='object')
> ```

Como existe ya una columna con el nombre `OK` a la siguiente le agrega el sufijo `.1`, dado que obviamente no pueden haber columnas con el mismo nombre en el mismo DataFrame.

Puedes pasarle `None` a `header`, con lo que no usara ninguna fila como *header*, pero aun así **pandas necesita darle un nombre a las columnas del DataFrame** y lo hará usando enteros:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", usecols=[0,3,4,5,6,7], skiprows=1, header=None)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>         0          3          4          5   6   7
> 0   Flaco  Fallecido       True         OK  OK  --
> 1  Pelado       Vivo  No existe  No existe  OK  --
> 2  Pajaro       Vivo  No existe  No existe  OK  --
> ```

Por lo tanto, o dejas que pandas use el header del csv para nombrar las columnas, o lo descartas y dejas que las nombre como en este ultimo ejemplo, o le pasas tu otros nombres explícitamente vía el argumento `name` junto a `header=0` y `skiprows=None` para que sobrescriba el `header` original, pero las columnas del *DataFrame* necesitan nombres únicos si o si..

Dicho esto, si lo que quieres es que no se escriba el header en el nuevo csv, no te compliques, pasale `header=False` a `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` y punto:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv, sep=";", usecols=[0,3,4,5,6,7])
df.to_csv("archivo.csv", index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Geniooo!! Muchas gracias por la explicación, mas allá de que me funciono no estaba entendiendo el porque, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas tardes Matias, si he entendido bien tu problema son los encabezados duplicados en las operaciones de importación y exportación.

Para solucionarlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

**- Eliminar la primera fila después de filtrar las columnas**
Puedes hacer esto usando el método `iloc` para seleccionar las filas desde la segunda en adelante:

```py
# Lee el archivo CSV y filtra las columnas
df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv", sep=";", usecols=[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], skiprows=1, header=0)

# Elimina la primera fila (fila duplicada)
df = df.iloc[1:]

# Exporta el archivo CSV sin encabezado duplicado
df.to_csv("archivo_salida.csv", index=False)
```

Otra opción es

**- Evitar la lectura de encabezados duplicados**
Asegurarte de que la primera fila del archivo CSV sea considerada como encabezado durante la lectura y, al mismo tiempo, utilizar `skiprows` para omitir la segunda fila (que es la original encabezado).

```py
# Lee el archivo CSV considerando la primera fila como encabezado
df = pd.read_csv("archivo.csv", sep=";", header=0, skiprows=[1], usecols=[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

# Exporta el archivo CSV sin encabezado duplicado
df.to_csv("archivo_salida.csv", index=False)
```

Espero que esto pueda ayudarte, un saludo.

Comment: Hola Jorch Buenas tardes!, Te comento, modifique el archivo para que se pueda leer mejor y coloque el importado crudo. 

Por lo que me comentas entendí que el "OK.1" aparece porque lo toma como un encabezado y al estar duplicado le genera un ".1".

El problema es que no son encabezados, no se porque la primer fila me la cuenta como encabezado, se los skipeo pero igual me toma un encabezado.

Lo que quiero lograr es que sean datos puros sin encabezado la salida para luego unirlos a varios csv. Sino entre medio de la union me van a quedar los encabezados.